# Can system notes be accessed via web services?

Tags: netsuite

I am developing a Net Suite application based on web services (SuiteTalk). I have learned about the concept of System Notes, which are a journal of changes on all types of objects. Yet, I see no way to access the list of system notes (say last N notes) via web services. Are you aware if this is possible and how? If not, what would be an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do it via a RESTlet/Suitelet, not sure about web services.

In JS you can do a search with a joint field on the results.. something like :

nlobjSearchColumn( 'date','systemnotes');

*I think is systemnotes.

Do the filter criteria on a UI search, and link that search to the service script, from there is pretty standard.